# Using Python, getting the name of files in a zip archive

Tags: python, zip, flask, werkzeug

I have several very large zip files available to download on a website. I am using Flask microframework (based on Werkzeug) which uses Python.

Is there a way to show the contents of a zip file (i.e. file and folder names) - to someone on a webpage - without actually downloading it? As in doing the working out server side.

Assume that I do not know what are in the zip archives myself.

I apoligize that this post does not include code.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sure, have a look at [`zipfile.ZipFile.namelist()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist). Usage is pretty simple, as you'd expect: you just create a `ZipFile` object for the file you want, and then `namelist()` gives you a list of the paths of files stored in the archive.

```
with ZipFile('foo.zip', 'r') as f:
    names = f.namelist()
print names
# ['file1', 'folder1/file2', ...]
```

Comment: oh heh, sorry @Andrew I didn't even notice your answer there, I was in such a hurry to edit mine ;-)

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html

Specifically, try using the ZipFile.namelist() method.